# sending a cross-origin POST request to localhost in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http-post, cross-domain

I am trying to use an XMLHttpRequest to POST some data to a server (currently localhost, but will later be remote) and retrieve the response. I am using the Cross-origin-resource sharing method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). However, I never receive the response data. The result is the same if I ignore the cross-origin issue and just send a normal XMLHttpRequest. I have verified using Postman that the URL sent is correct (JSON data is returned). Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Thanks very much!

```
// taken from StackOverflow
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

function sendRequest() {
    var theUrl = "http://localhost:4567/myApi?input="
      + encodeURIComponent("some text input");
    alert(theUrl); // verified this is correct using Postman
    var request = createCORSRequest("POST", theUrl);
    if (request){
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          console.log(request); // shows responseText empty
          alert("http returned " + request.responseText);
        };
        request.send();
    }
}
```

The console.logged request looks like:

```
XMLHttpRequest {}
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: ()
ontimeout: null
readyState: 4
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType: ""
responseURL: ""
responseXML: null
status: 0
statusText: ""
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUploadwithCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Where does it break down? Open your browser's developer tools. Look in the Console. Are there errors? Look in the Net tab. Do you see the request? Is it formatted as you expect? What about the response? Does it have the right content type? Does it have the right body content?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the network tab. The POST request says status:"canceled"!  And the localhost:4567 is omitted from the "name" column; it just says myApi?input=....

But I did verify that var theUrl is as expected. Any idea if/how this URL is getting truncated before being sent across the network and canceled?

Comment: Is there an OPTION request before the POST request? If not, how are you triggering the JS? If you send the XHR request immediately before leaving the page, it will get canceled.

Comment: @Quentin browsers will send the preflight request automatically. I guess the problem is that the server isn't sending the CORS headers in response to that.

Comment: There's no OPTION request - why and how would I send an option request?
I'm triggering the request by calling request.send(). I also know that request.onreadystatechange is getting called. I'm not leaving the page at all. How could I prevent the request from getting canceled?

Comment: @EllenSebastian — The OPTION request will be sent if you make a *complex* cross-origin request. If the browser isn't making one then don't worry about it, that just means you don't have to deal with it on the server.

Comment: The problem seems to be the missing data for the `name` in the query string. I can't see any way that it would get lost with this code though.

Comment: The server **is** receiving the POST request with the correct data and returning some JSON - even though the request appears as "canceled".  It appears, from the server logs, that the JSON is getting returned **after** onreadystatechange is called. So I suppose something is preventing the browser from receiving the server's response.

Comment: @EllenSebastian most likely it's because your server isn't following the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) protocol. The browser expects the server to send Accept-Origin, Accept-Methods and other CORS headers in response to the preflight OPTIONS request. Failing that, the browser will cancel the request.

Comment: @Touffy — If that was the case there would be an obvious error message in the Console. Also, the OP said there wasn't a preflight options request.

Comment: `onreadystatechange` gets changed every time the state changes. So it should get called multiple times over the lifetime of the request and only show the response text in the last version of it.

Comment: @Touffy This sounds right. The server has literally nothing other than myApi. Thanks very much!
@Quentin, `onreadystatechange` only gets called once, with `readyState==4.`

Comment: I enabled CORS on the server using [this tutorial](https://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/02/20/spas-and-enabling-cors-in-spark/) and the behavior is the same. It is possible that I did not enable CORS correctly though.

Comment: Nothing in the console and Network debugger? also, instead of `'*'`, it's better to reflect the request's value in the CORS response headers (i.e. set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the request's Origin, and so on). Under some circumstances, `'*'` is not allowed.

Comment: In the network tab, if I click on the name of my request (`myApi?input=...`), then in the headers tab it shows that the request URL is actually `http://localhost:4567/myApi?input=...`. So the request URL is actually correct.

Comment: Does your server receive the preflight OPTIONS request? maybe it's ignoring it? I'm not familiar with Spark but it may be that the tutorial you linked is only giving instructions for adding headers to simple GET requests, not responding to OPTIONS.

Comment: from what I can tell, the server does not receive any options request.

Comment: again, the server IS sending a response; the problem is just that the client does not receive it.

Comment: Does the network tab say anything about sending one, or is the browser sending the POST request directly? can you post the Origin and all Access-Control-Request-* headers sent with the request?

Comment: Oh, and are you sending a cookie with the request, and does the server expect a cookie? (if it does, you're screwed)

Comment: I am not sure about your first question. I know that the POST request is being sent because the server receives it. In the network tab, it is shown as Canceled.
The Origin header is null. I don't see any Access-Control-Request-* header. I am not sending any cookies and the server doesn't expect any.

Comment: In your browser's network tab, it would look like this (in WebKit): http://tffy.free.fr/network-options.png

Comment: Origin is null, huh… are you loading the page from a `file://` URL?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Chrome javascript console, and the layout is similar; there are just no Access-Control-Request-* headers: http://imgur.com/leHp1ho

The screenshot was taken while the "http returned" alert is shown.

Comment: Yes, the page is a file:// url: I'm developing locally.

Comment: Can you try hosting the page on an HTTP server (on a different port than your API)? any server will do. CORS is a bit broken with file:// origins.

Comment: will do; installing XAMPP

Comment: running my html file on localhost using XAMPP, the result is the same as before except `origin==http://localhost`. (no port yet - I'm working on running on a specific port)

Comment: same result when running on port 8888 except `origin==http://localhost:8888`. Should I try to set the Access-Control-Request-* headers in my javascript XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: No, they should be added automatically by the browser when needed, as well as the preflight request. I don't understand why Chrome isn't doing it.

Comment: `Access-Control-*` headers are **response** headers. They shouldn't be added by the browser (or put on the request at all).